# Can I install a Steam game on two drives?

Tags: steam, hard-drive

Can I install a Steam game on two hard drives? I already have a game installed on my solid state from a transfer, but that folder is full of mods and ENB files, and it's quite messy. I want to install the game on a separate drive to try and clean things up without compromising my current setup.

Is it possible to install a Steam game on a second hard drive if it already exists on one?

Comment: You can "hide" games from steam simply by renaming the folder under "...steamapps/common/[game's folder]", but there doesn't seem to be a way to trick it into thinking a game isn't installed (which would give you the option to install to another location).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but moving an already-installed game from it's installed folder may be tricky. Unless its insanely huge, I'd recommend backing up any save games or user content to another location, deleting the local content via Steam, and reinstalling it under the new drive location, then moving all of your savegames back into place.

There are Steam forum posts and links about this, some of which can be found here:

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2965732

and here:

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7418-YUBN-8129

For me personally, I'd do what I mentioned above, because I've run into issues. It may have been my mistake, or an issue with a particular game, so I choose to do it "the safe way" from now on. YMMV.

Comment: So there's no way for Steam to do a dual install? I figured I might have to do it manually, but that seems like something the client can do.

Comment: Dual? You're talking about having two copies of the game installed in Steam? That's not possible as far as I know. Trying to install a game would result in Steam telling you that it's already installed. Who knows how bad it may mess up Steam if you try it.

Comment: Well, now that you put it that way, it does seem kind of strange. I can simply keep the folder structure as it is, in a different spot, and rebuild the game/mods/ENB files in the original location.

Answer (score 0):

The place steam stores its games is only for steam. You can go into your `settings` > `Downloads` and create a new location for your library (makes future installs easier). Once you've done that, copy the game folder to your new location manually.

Now from the steam library, choose `Add a game...` > `Add a non-steam game`

Browse to the new folder's exe file, and you'll have two instances of the same game in your steam library.